# How to run this script once?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not a programmer, so maybe the info that I looking for in somewhere but I don't know How to search for it.

I have this script to post recent posts by category. It will get the latest published posts from that category forever without ending. If there any solution to make it run once.

Example: If I put this code into a blog post, I want it to post the latest 5 posts only from a specific category, and stop getting any new published posts from that category after that.

I don't know if you understand what I mean or not, but excuse me because I'm not a programmer.

Thank You..

```
    <style>
/*Recent Post By tag*/
img.recent-thumb{float:left;margin-right:10px;height:50px;width:50px;}
.recent-by-tag{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
ul.recent-by-tag li{padding:10px 0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:28px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}
.recent-by-tag li{font-size:13px;list-style:none;padding-left:0;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
.recent-by-tag a{font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;margin:0;}
.recent-by-tag strong{padding-left:0}
span.showdates{font-size:14px;margin:10px 0 0}</style>
<div id="rcentDiv">
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var numposts = 10;
var showpostthumbnails = true;
var showpostdate = false;
// Recent Post By Tag
// Recent Post By Tag For Blogger
// insert revised rcentbytag() code here
function rcentbytag(e) {
    var storedHTML = "";
    function saveHTML(h) {
        storedHTML += h;
    }
    saveHTML('<table><tbody><tr><td><ul class="recent-by-tag">');
    for (var t = 0; t < numposts; t++) {
        var n = e.feed.entry[t];
        var r = n.title.$t;
        var i;
        if (t == e.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var o = 0; o < n.link.length; o++) {
            if (n.link[o].rel == "replies" && n.link[o].type == "text/html") {
                var u = n.link[o].title;
                var f = n.link[o].href
            }
            if (n.link[o].rel == "alternate") {
                i = n.link[o].href;
                break
            }
        }
        var l;
        try {
            l = n.media$thumbnail.url
        } catch (h) {
            s = n.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf('src="', a);
            c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if (a != -1 && b != -1 && c != -1 && d != "") {
                l = d
            } else l = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-giova1ZCh-A/Uzq6L8QTJNI/AAAAAAAAAJc/USXictTq_xs/s70-c/KM+Icon.png"
        }
        var p = n.published.$t;
        var v = p.substring(0, 4);
        var m = p.substring(5, 7);
        var g = p.substring(8, 10);
        var y = new Array;
        y[1] = "January";
        y[2] = "February";
        y[3] = "March";
        y[4] = "April";
        y[5] = "May";
        y[6] = "June";
        y[7] = "July";
        y[8] = "August";
        y[9] = "September";
        y[10] = "October";
        y[11] = "November";
        y[12] = "December";
        saveHTML('<li class="clear">');
        if (showpostthumbnails == true) saveHTML('<a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '"><img class="recent-thumb" alt="' + r + '" src="' + l + '"/></a>');
        saveHTML('<strong><a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '">' + r + '</a></strong>');
        saveHTML('<br>');
        var x = "";
        var T = 0;
        if (showpostdate == true) {
            x = '<span class="showdates">' + x + g + " " + y[parseInt(m, 10)] + " " + v + "</span>";
            T = 1
        }
        saveHTML(x);
        saveHTML("</li>");
        if (t != numposts - 1) saveHTML("")
    }
    saveHTML("</ul></td></tr></tbody></table>")
    document.getElementById("rcentDiv").innerHTML = storedHTML;
}
</script>
<script async="async" src="https://www.example.com/feeds/posts/default/-/CategoryName?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=rcentbytag" return false;"></script>
```

Comment: Currently, does this also show new posts as they are created?

Comment: Yes, It shows the new posts forever. If I published a new blog post in the selected category, the code will show it, and so on.

Comment: I want it to post latest 5 posts only once, and never changing it again.

Comment: Do you mean that 1.) you load the page where this code is, it loads posts 2.) in another browser you create new posts 3.) back in browser #1 the new posts automatically show up (with page reloading) ?

Comment: @KayakinKoder Exactly, So I want it to show the latest posts for the time I published it only, after that when publishing new posts I want it (The Code) to do nothing anymore.

Comment: Yeah, providing a URL would be good

Comment: Ok, Go to this link: https://www.yes-android.com/2018/02/a310fxxu3cql2-galaxy-a3-2016-sm-a310f-stock-firmware-download.html , and under that title "More Samsung Galaxy A3 Firmware Downloads" you will see the results from the code that you edited. I set the category to "Galaxy A3", and it worked well. After that I published a new post in the same category "Galaxy A3" https://www.yes-android.com/2018/02/a320fxxu3bra1-galaxy-a3-2017-sm-a320f-official-firmware.html and if you take a look to the code results, you will find it displayed the latest post that I have published, and I don't want that.

Comment: I want it to grab the latest 5 post from the feed for one time only and after that stop grapping the new posts, so the 5 posts that the code printed will never change again.

Comment: Ok, give the updated code in my answer a try

Comment: I can't ask you more because I will be embarrassed from you. Anyway, the new code worked with the same result, but If I set maxposts to 5 and the category has only 3, the code will show nothing. If you don't mind, take a quick look at this picture, I explained the Idea in it.https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-1xeek5FWnz4/WooF6kasOYI/AAAAAAAAR0s/ZezjUtlnEKwqiOadEDvaHs1nKT0wLSb4QCLcBGAs/s1600/Recent-By-Tag-Code-Explain.JPG  >>>>>  Anyway, Thank You very much for your help as you tried more and more with my alien code :)

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that the code now successfully only shows 5 posts and not more?

Comment: @KayakinKoder  No, I mean I set the maxposts=5, as you wrote it, but the category that I set have only 2 posts. After publishing the code, it doesn't work, so I reset the maxposts=5 to maxposts=2. I refreshed the page and found the code worked well. But this code also didn't solve my problem. If you looked at the picture that I provided you, you will understand my point more. Thank You

Comment: Ok, sorry, your image goes far beyond your original question of limiting the posts to 5. Please accept my answer as it does solve the problem of limiting posts to 5, then create a new question with the new problems you're facing

Comment: I will accept it, but  I said 5 posts as an example, and I can show the number that I want by setting numpost=(number). Anyway, I will accept your answer because you worked well and hard with me, but instead of asking a new question as I will ask it in the same way, could you please help me her?

Comment: Ok let me make sure I am clear; you have 6 blog posts. The page shows 1 - 5, but you want it to show 2 - 6 ?

Comment: No my friend, forget the numbers. I want the results that code printed stay without any updating anymore. I'm saying numbers as an example only because I can control the number that the code will show. As you can see in the picture, the code will update its results after publishing a new post like the Blog Feeds, and I don't want that. I want it to show results one time only, and stop updating them, So If I published a new post and refreshed the page that containing the code, the results will not change anymore.

Comment: Ohhh, *after* the page reloads you want it to be the same as it was. I see now. That is not possible with the tools you have here; the reason is, when the page reloads, it has no way of "remembering" what was there the last time the page loaded. To accomplish that, you will need to contact a software developer to help; there are a few options (cookies, database value, url query string) to accomplish it, but it will take quite a bit of work

Comment: @KayakinKoder oooh I don't know that, I thought it will be an easy edit in this code. Thank You very much. Really I appreciate your help and your hard work. Thank You again KayakinKoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all of your code with this, let me know if it works; after changing the page make sure you hard refresh the page (ctrl + F5 in google chrome) to get the new content. Note that there are a lot of bad practices in the code you provided and that I've only slightly edited here; if this is for a production website I highly recommend hiring a developer who is familiar with modern javascript techniques like ES6 modules.

```
<style>
/*Recent Post By tag*/
img.recent-thumb{float:left;margin-right:10px;height:50px;width:50px;}
.recent-by-tag{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
ul.recent-by-tag li{padding:10px 0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:28px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}
.recent-by-tag li{font-size:13px;list-style:none;padding-left:0;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
.recent-by-tag a{font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;margin:0;}
.recent-by-tag strong{padding-left:0}
span.showdates{font-size:14px;margin:10px 0 0}</style>
<div id="rcentDiv">
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var limitreached = false;
var maxposts = 5;
var numposted = 0;
var showpostthumbnails = true;
var showpostdate = false;
// Recent Post By Tag
// Recent Post By Tag For Blogger
// insert revised rcentbytag() code here
function rcentbytag(e) {
    if (limitreached === false) {
        var storedHTML = "";

        function saveHTML(h) {
            storedHTML += h;
        }

        saveHTML('<table><tbody><tr><td><ul class="recent-by-tag">');
        for (var t = 0; t < maxposts; t++) {
            numposted = numposted + 1;
            if (numposted > maxposts) {
                limitreached = true;
            }

            if (limitreached === false) {
                var n = e.feed.entry[t];
                var r = n.title.$t;
                var i;
                if (t == e.feed.entry.length) break;
                for (var o = 0; o < n.link.length; o++) {
                    if (n.link[o].rel == "replies" && n.link[o].type == "text/html") {
                        var u = n.link[o].title;
                        var f = n.link[o].href
                    }
                    if (n.link[o].rel == "alternate") {
                        i = n.link[o].href;
                        break
                    }
                }
                var l;
                try {
                    l = n.media$thumbnail.url
                } catch (h) {
                    s = n.content.$t;
                    a = s.indexOf("<img");
                    b = s.indexOf('src="', a);
                    c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5);
                    d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
                    if (a != -1 && b != -1 && c != -1 && d != "") {
                        l = d
                    } else l = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-giova1ZCh-A/Uzq6L8QTJNI/AAAAAAAAAJc/USXictTq_xs/s70-c/KM+Icon.png"
                }
                var p = n.published.$t;
                var v = p.substring(0, 4);
                var m = p.substring(5, 7);
                var g = p.substring(8, 10);
                var y = new Array;
                y[1] = "January";
                y[2] = "February";
                y[3] = "March";
                y[4] = "April";
                y[5] = "May";
                y[6] = "June";
                y[7] = "July";
                y[8] = "August";
                y[9] = "September";
                y[10] = "October";
                y[11] = "November";
                y[12] = "December";
                saveHTML('<li class="clear">');
                if (showpostthumbnails == true) {
                    saveHTML('<a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '"><img class="recent-thumb" alt="' + r + '" src="' + l + '"/></a>');
                }
                saveHTML('<strong><a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '">' + r + '</a></strong>');
                saveHTML('<br>');
                var x = "";
                var T = 0;
                if (showpostdate == true) {
                    x = '<span class="showdates">' + x + g + " " + y[parseInt(m, 10)] + " " + v + "</span>";
                    T = 1
                }
                saveHTML(x);
                saveHTML("</li>");
                if (t != maxposts - 1) {
                    saveHTML("");
                }
            }
        }
        saveHTML("</ul></td></tr></tbody></table>");
        document.getElementById("rcentDiv").innerHTML = storedHTML;
    }
}
</script>
<script async="async" src="https://www.example.com/feeds/posts/default/-/CategoryName?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=rcentbytag" return false;"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, I will try and back to you with the results.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work. There are some mistakes happened beside the code didn't do what I want. First, It displayed 10 posts although I set it to post 5 only. Second: When I refreshed the page, it showed posts from another category, when I refreshed again, it displayed the selected category, and so on. Third: I'm sure I'm not able to make you understand my point. I'm using this code to get related posts from the same category of the current post, it's useful for SEO, but I don't want the code to change the results even when I published a new post in the selected category.

Comment: I want the code to show the latest posts from that category and stop showing new posts. I want it to run for one time only and the results that displayed still the same even if there are new published posts in that category. I hope that I have been able to clarify the idea for you. Thank You for your help.

Comment: @AhmedSheta sorry without having more of your server-side code, we can't help more than this. Both solution and the other one posted would stop the code from printing more than a single set of posts.

Comment: 1 Sorry for bothering you, you guys are so awesome. Anyway, I will give you some extra info. I'm using a Blogger blog, Into post HTML code I paste this code in any are of the post, Then it will display (e.g 5 posts) from a specific category, after publishing the post, the code will print 5 posts from that category, but if I published a new post in that category, the code will display this new post as Num1 and delete the last one and so on. I want it to print the 5 results for one time only, and never updated again if there are any new posts from that category.

Comment: 1 As you know I'm grabbing this posts from my blog feeds. You can imagine this code as a person, who print the new post once it get published, and keep watching on the category updates, if any new posts get published it will display it, and so on. So I want to stop the code from updating the 5 results that printed.

Comment: Sorry, I found a conflict with the same code in another widget. I will try it again to see the final result. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I tried it, but it still getting the new updates from the specified category. If you want me to provide you with URLs, tell me.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean (yes/no value) to check if the function has been ran already.

```
var CodeRan;

function YourFunction(){
  if(!CodeRan){ // If CodeRan is false...
    // Set CodeRan to true, so the next time the function is called it wont get past the If statement.      
    CodeRan = true;

    // Your code goes here.
  } // End of IF statement.
} // End of yourFunction
```

Possible duplicate of this:
[Javascript running code once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470516/javascript-running-code-once)

Comment: I will try your code, and back to you with the result. Thank You.

Comment: Doesn't work, When I ran the code, the code doesn't work. I want it to post latest 5 posts only once, and never changing it again.

Comment: Try changing "if(!codeRan)" to "if(codeRan < 5)", which checks to see if the integer is less than 5.  Then change "codeRan = true" to "codeRan++" which increments codeRan once each time.  Once it hits 5 it wont run again.